# Auto incremento personalizado

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

Eu tenho que gerar um auto incremento do tipo `"000"+id`, mas não consigo chegar em algo concreto, a minha base é essa abaixo, queria só uma luz mesmo de como fazer, não preciso da resposta em si.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue                                 
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: Qual o seu banco de dados?

Comment: sql server 2008

Comment: A ideia é no final guardar na `BD`, no campo do `ID` que é do tipo `Long` uma `String` com o prefixo `000`? Ou percebi mal @haykou

Comment: Isso, eu fiz outro campo com o nome de código mas passando public string GetCodigo() { return codigo }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem várias opções. Uma ideia é criar um coluna computada auxiliar a `identity` no banco de dados (veja [esse artigo](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server)):

```
CREATE TABLE MinhaTabela
( 
 DbID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE FUNCTION GeraID (@id int) 
RETURNS CHAR(5) 
AS 
BEGIN
RETURN RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @id), 5) 
END;

ALTER TABLE MinhaTabela ADD MeuID as DBO.GeraID(DbID);
```

O hibernate possui uma anotação (específica, não standard do JPA) para recuperar valores gerados ([`@Generated`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Generated.html)).

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT) 
@Column(name = "MeuID", insertable = false)
String meuID;
```

Se não quiser usar nada específico do Hibernate será necessário fazer um `refresh` da sua entidade após persisti-la para obter a coluna computada.

---

Algumas outras idéias:

- Criar um [gerador customizado](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-identifier) com [`@GenericGenerator`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html).
- Usar um [`@NaturalID`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2767) para identificar o ID com máscara.
- Não persistir a máscara no banco e criar um *getter* do lado do java (do tipo `public String getIDComMascara()`)

Comment: Para Sql Server 2012 pra frente, podemos utilizar [`Sequences`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ff878091.aspx)